# Webscrape Google Movies with Goutte/Guzzle: "region" issue

Tags: php, web-scraping, region, guzzle, goutte

I created a simple webscraper with [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) to grab some movie showtimes for some application. I use this king of URL, for instance : http://www.google.fr/movies?view=list&date=3&tid=4f451a87a71bfa51.

The code isn't working on my production server, and I finally noticed that Google Movies won't show the results depending on the requester location. The theatre is in France, and it's obviously working from this country, and from Germany too as far I can see, but not from Netherlands, which is my production server location.

Has anybody encountered a problem like this one? I think I could resolve this with a proxy, but it seems a little complicated (do I have to set up a new server in France just for this purpose?); maybe there's a way to tweak the HTTP request made to Google Movies?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okaaay, I found it. The trick is to add a "near" param in the querystring, with a country or region name. Seems that the "tid" isn't enough to identify the theatre.

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: I'm also stuck in similar situation. Could you please explain your method in little detail?

Comment: Mmm, that's an old one, and since Google Movies disappeared, but I think the trick was just to add a `?near=france` (in my case) in the querystring, to give to a "from location" clue — as the service would normally use the browser / IP location for that.

Comment: Actually I'm building an price comparison site which scrap data from different sites and display them on same page. Only problem I'm facing is difference in shipping price because server is hosted in Bulgaria and results are according to Bulgaria.

Comment: But, I want to show shipping price according to user's location.
Here is website I'm working on: http://hardwareguru.net/